# How to solve this error "TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'image' of 'undefined' as it is undefined"? Below is my code-

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined, typeerror

React Js
I am getting following error -
"TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'image' of 'undefined' as it is undefined"? Below is my code "
how can I solve this, why its showing undefined is the way which I defined is correct.....?

Can someone please help?

Below is the code in React JS

````
    import React from 'react';
    // import profile from '../assets/rocket.svg';
    import styled from 'styled-components';
    import { useSpring, animated, config } from 'react-spring';
    import "../css/Card.css"
    
    
    const Container = styled(animated.div)`
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0em;
    background: #C7D2FE66;
    border-radius: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    background-clip: border-box;
    // cursor: pointer;
    
    `;
    
    const StyledImg = styled.img`
        width: 500px;
        height:auto;
        // height: auto;
        border: 2px solid #000;
        // border-radius: 50%;
    `;
    
    const StyledH1 = styled.h1`
        line-heright: 1.5;
        letter-spacing: 1.5;
        font-family: "Gilroy";
    `;
    
    const StyledH3 = styled.h3`
        line-heright: 1.5;
        letter-spacing: 1.15;
        font-family: "Gilroy";
        font-size: 20px;
    `;
    
    const calc = (x, y) => [-(y - window.innerHeight / 2) / 20, (x - window.innerWidth / 2) / 20, 1]
    const trans = (x, y, s) => `perspective(600px) rotateX(${x}deg) rotateY(${y}deg) scale(${s})`

    function Card({ heading }, { description }, { image }) {
        const [props, set] = useSpring(() => ({ xys: [0, 0, 1], config: config.default }))
        return (
            <Container
                onMouseMove={({ clientX: x, clientY: y }) => (set({ xys: calc(x, y) }))}
                onMouseLeave={() => set({ xys: [0, 0, 1] })}
                style={{
                    transform: props.xys.interpolate(trans)
                }}
            >
    
                <StyledH1>{heading}</StyledH1>
                <StyledH3>{description} <br /> </StyledH3>
                <StyledImg src={image} />
            </Container>
        );
    }
    
    export default Card;
    
    ```
````

Comment: that's not how you destructure multiple properties of a single object. `function Card({ heading }, { description }, { image })` should be `function Card({ heading, description, image })`. As you have it now, you're accepting 3 arguments, each presumed to be an object with the appropriate property - but react function components accept a single ("props") object as a parameter.

Comment: Can you show us where you are using "Card" and how you are passing in props

Comment: Thank you for the correction @RobinZigmond